# find `A` raised to `B`, then you need to multiply A to itself B number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

'i am not getting the correct output while giving(9,-8).how to solve this without using pow function and ** operator'

```
def power(x,y):
    if x == 0:
        return x
    if y == -1:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1   
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    a = power(x,y//2)
    if y%2 == 0:
        return a*a
    return a*a*x
print power(9,-8)
```

Comment: And that error is..?

Comment: And please format the code properly, especially important when Python is used

Comment: @AndrewLi. am getting the output as:-1.Its not the correct output

Comment: @vivin: Please check my edited answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def power(x,y):
   if y == 0:
    return 1
   a = power(x, y/2);
   if y%2 == 0:
    return a*a;
   else:
    return x*a*a;

x = 9
y = -8
if y < 0:
    print 1.0/(power(x,abs(y)))
else:
    print power(x,abs(y))
```

Keep it simple like this..

My pow() function calculates `x^y` when `y` is positive. If we want to find `x^y` for a negative `y`, then simply print `1/pow(x,y)`

Note: @vivin: Does it answer correctly now?

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: " -power(x,abs(y)) " - Cant understand the '-' in power function?

Comment: @vivin: Please give a test case where my code fails??

Comment: @AndrewLi: My mistake. Added explanation. I thought the code was self explanatory.. :P

Comment: @vivin If you're going to tell someone that they are wrong, then tell them _why_ they are wrong.

Comment: @DineshPundkar: Sorry dinesh. my mistake. Modified the code. Hope you understand this

Comment: @User_Targaryen but the output for the (9,-8) is "2.3230573125418773e-08"

Comment: @User_Targaryen Thanks for ypur support

Comment: @vivin: Check the actual answer. https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=9%5E-8                         
`(9,-8)` = `1/(9,8)` = `1/9^8` = `2.323 * 10^-8` which is written as `2.3230573125418773e-08`

Comment: @User_Targaryen yaa got it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code will always return -1 if y != -1 (unless x == 0) because of

```
if y == -1:
    return 1
else:
    return -1
```

Keep it simple ;)

```
def power(x,y):
    if y==0: return 1
    if x in [0,1] or y==1 : return x
    return x*power(x,y-1) if y > 0 else 1.0/power(x,-y)
```